# Convert to datetime array where fractional seconds are only sometimes present?

Tags: matlab, date, datetime

I have a cell array containing date formatted strings, and I would like to convert the entire array into a datetime array. The problem is that some of the strings contain fractional seconds (with varying degrees of precision), whereas others do not, like this:

```
my_date_strings{1} = '2022-01-15T14:04:58.23Z'  ;
my_date_strings{2} = '2022-01-15T14:19:28Z'     ;
my_date_strings{3} = '2022-01-08T09:43:24.702Z' ;
my_datetime = datetime(my_date_strings, 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS''Z''' );
```

How can I specify the Input Format for datetime in such a way that it can handle both types? (Ideally, I would like to ignore the fractional seconds on every element, but can it be done using the input format specifier?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexp is hard. [`erase`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/erase.html) using a [`pattern`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pattern.html) is easier.

```matlab
>> x = erase(my_date_strings, "." + digitsPattern)
x =
  1×3 cell array
    {'2022-01-15T14:04:58Z'}    {'2022-01-15T14:19:28Z'}    {'2022-01-08T09:43:24Z'}
>> my_datetime = datetime(x, 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss''Z''' )
my_datetime = 
  1×3 datetime array
   2022-Jan-15 14:04:58   2022-Jan-15 14:19:28   2022-Jan-08 09:43:24
```

Comment: Just re-read the question and see the OP wants to discard the fractional seconds... which makes this a nice answer

Comment: This is beautiful. Does exactly the job, and I have also learned two new features to leverage in Matlab from now on (erase function and Pattern objects). Thanks for pointing out these functions!

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the strings which are missing the fractional seconds so they end `.00` and your format is then consistent. If you know that every element of `my_date_strings` ends either `':ss.SSZ'` or `':ssZ'` then you can just check for the decimal point 3 characters from the end, and replace `'Z'` with `.00Z` if it's missing. This might look like:

```
my_date_strings{1} = '2022-01-15T14:04:58.23Z';
my_date_strings{2} = '2022-01-15T14:19:28Z';

% Check which dates have the decimal point 3 characters from the end
hasMS = cellfun( @(x) x(end-3) == '.', my_date_strings );
% For those where it's missing, add it in
my_date_strings( ~hasMS ) = strrep( my_date_strings( ~hasMS ), 'Z', '.00Z' );

% Do a consistent conversion
my_datetime = datetime(my_date_strings, 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS''Z''' );
```

If the number of digits after the decimal place can vary then you need something marginally more complicated... You can define the "padding" as `'.000Z'` and work out how many characters of this padding each date string needs. Then stick that much padding on the end. I think the clearest way to do this is in a little loop, noting that a "full" 3-decimal-place date string in your defined format has 24 characters:

```
ms = '.000Z';
n = 24 - cellfun( @numel, my_date_strings );
for ii = 1:numel(my_date_strings)
    my_date_strings{ii} = [my_date_strings{ii}(1:end-1), ms(end-n(ii):end)];
end

my_datetime = datetime(my_date_strings, 'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS''Z''' );
```

Comment: @teeeeee please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, based on splitting the strings into the relevant parts using a very simple regular expression. This has no restrictions on the number of decimals.

1. Use [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to match sections of each string consisting of one or more occurrences of any characters except `'-'`, `'T'`, `':'` or `'Z'`. For each string this will produce 6 substrings corresponding to year, month, day, hour, minute and second, and the latter will contain the decimal part if it exists. Due to how `regexp` works, the result is a cell array of cell arrays.
2. Convert to a two-dimensional, non-nested cell array using [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.vertcat.html) with a [comma-separated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) list. Now each row refers to one of the original strings, and each column is one of its 6 substrings.
3. Convert each substring to a number, using [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html). This gives a numerical matrix of 6 columns.
4. Separate the matrix into a cell array of its 6 columns using [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html).
5. Pass a comma-separted list of the 6 columns as inputs to [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to produce the desired output.

```
my_date_strings{1} = '2022-01-15T14:04:58.23Z' ;
my_date_strings{2} = '2022-01-15T14:19:28Z'    ;
my_date_strings{3} = '2022-01-08T09:43:24.702Z';
str = regexp(my_date_strings, '[^-T:Z]+', 'match'); % step 1
str = vertcat(str{:});                              % step 2
num = str2double(str);                              % step 3
num = num2cell(num, 1);                             % step 4
my_datetime = datetime(num{:});                     % step 5
```

Note that, although the default display method does not indicate fractions of seconds,

```
>> my_datetime
my_datetime = 
  3×1 datetime array
   15-Jan-2022 14:04:58
   15-Jan-2022 14:19:28
   08-Jan-2022 09:43:24
```

they are actually there:

```
>> second(my_datetime)
ans =
   58.2300
   28.0000
   24.7020
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to preserve the fractional seconds:

```
s = textscan([my_date_strings{:}], repmat('%f%*c', 1, 6));
my_datetime = datetime(s{:});
```